# Representing Mongoose model as a Typescript class

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, typescript, angular

I'm writing a simple web application using Angular 2 written in TypeScript.  MongoDB is my database on a Mongoose framework while running on a Node server on an Express framework.  My MongoDB and Node code is written in vanilla JS.

Now, I created a Mongoose model for a Country as following:

```
"use strict";
const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema,
      db = require('../../config/database');

let countrySchema = new Schema({
  countryName: { type: String, index : { unique : true } }
});

let Country = db.model('Country', countrySchema);

module.exports = Country;
```

Now, Country is what I want my object to be.  In my app component, I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CountryService } from '../services/country.service';
import { Country } from '../models/country.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/app.component.html',
  providers: [ CountryService ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  originCountries: Country[];
  destinationCountries: Country[];
  constructor(private countryService: CountryService) { };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCountries();
  }

  getCountries() {
    this.countryService.getCountries()
      .then(countries => {
        this.originCountries = countries;
        this.destinationCountries = countries;
      });
  }
}
```

See how originCountries and destinationCountries should be arrays of Countries?  I can't just import Country from the Country model (even though it sounded right in my head at the time).

What is the best way to create a country class that is based on the Mongoose model?

Comment: I am not very well acquainted with TypeScript, but wouldn't something like this do the deed: https://github.com/Appsilon/styleguide/wiki/mongoose-typescript-models ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use an interface like this ICountry:

```
export interface ICountry {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

You can now use this interface in your mongoose setup:

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
import { ICountry } from './interfaces';

var _schema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } }
});

type CountryType = ICountry & mongoose.Document;

var _model = mongoose.model <CountryType> ('Country', _schema);

export class Country {

  static getAll(): Promise<Array<ICountry>> {
    return new Promise<ICountry> ((resolve, reject) => {
      _model.find((err, counties) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(counties);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And the route setup:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/api/countries', (req, res) => {
      Country.getAll().then(c => {
        return res.json(c);
      });
    });
```

And implement it in your Angular application, if you need some methods or just import the interface direct in your service class:

```
import { ICountry } from '../../interfaces';
...
countries: Array<ICountry>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it in my project:

In my schema file:

```
///<reference path="../typings/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts"/>

import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    // ...
});

export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    // ...
}

export interface IUserModel extends mongoose.Model<IUser> { }

export var User: IUserModel = <IUserModel>mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

In the server side code:

```
import {User, IUser, IUserModel} from '../schemas/user.schema';

// ...

User.findOne({ ... });
```

In the client side code I now can use the `IUser` interface:

```
import {IUser} from '../---/schemas/user.schema';

// ...

userCache: Array<IUser>;
```

Comment: We do it almost the same, but I like to decouple the interface from the Document class.

Comment: See @DNRN 's answer! He showed how you can combine the interface and Document type to a new type.